# Groupby and Multi indexing

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a very large Dataframe which is indexed by datetime. I am using groupby to create a new table as following

`pivot5min1 = df1.groupby(by=[lambda x: dt.datetime(x.year,x.month,x.day,x.hour,x.minute - (x.minute % 5)),'ACCOUNT','TICKER'], as_index=True, sort=True, group_keys=False).agg(sum)`

However, I cannot seem to access data from this new dataframe in the most obvious intuitive way. First the follow is the index sample as given by `pivot5min1.index[:5]`

`MultiIndex
[(2013-06-19 09:30:00, u'ACCT1', u'ABC'), (2013-06-19 09:30:00, u'ACCT1', u'MNP'), (2013-06-19 09:30:00, u'ACCT1', u'XYZ')]`

I can access the first row as following:

`pivot5min1.loc[('2013-06-19 09:30:00', 'ACCT1')].loc['ABC']`

but when I try to use `pivot5min1.loc[('2013-06-19 09:30:00', 'ACCT1', 'ABC')]` I get the following error:

`KeyError: 'the label [ACCT1] is not in the [columns]'`

Comment: Can you post a couple rows of the summed dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right this should be the obvious way to access a row, but there seems an issue with the datetime part of the MultiIndex (I think this is a bug, as it works with only two levels of the three levels, but not with three. And it also works when the datetime is the only index).

As a workaround, you can use an explicit pandas Timestamp instead of a string, this works:

```
>>> df= pd.DataFrame({'ACCOUNT':["ACCT1", "ACCT1", "ACCT1", "ACCT2"],
...                   'TICKER':["ABC", "MNP", "XYZ", "XYZ"], 
...                   'val':[1,2,3,4]},
...                  index=pd.date_range("2013-06-19 09:30:00", periods=4, freq='5T'))
>>> df = df.set_index(['ACCOUNT', 'TICKER'], append=True)
>>>
>>> df.loc[(pd.Timestamp('2013-06-19 09:30:00'), 'ACCT1', 'ABC')]
val    1
Name: (2013-06-19 09:30:00, ACCT1, ABC), dtype: int64
```

while with a string it doesn't, as you reported:

```
>>> df.loc[('2013-06-19 09:30:00', 'ACCT1', 'ABC')]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 697, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 258, in _getitem_tuple
    self._has_valid_tuple(tup)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 692, in _has_valid_tuple
    if not self._has_valid_type(k,i):
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 767, in _has_valid_type
    raise KeyError("the label [%s] is not in the [%s]" % (key,self.obj._get_axis_name(axis)))
KeyError: 'the label [ACCT1] is not in the [columns]'
>>> df.loc[(pd.Timestamp('2013-06-19 09:30:00', tz=None), 'ACCT1', 'ABC')]
val    1
Name: (2013-06-19 09:30:00, ACCT1, ABC), dtype: int64
```